# Convert Mysql to Sqlite database

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a MySql database with different language(English, Hindi, Tamil,...) contents, to convert it into sqlite I have to run this (http://www.jbip.net/content/how-convert-mysql-sqlite) Script.  When I export the mysql db with this command `mysqldump -u root -p --compatible=ansi --skip-opt generator > dumpfile` contents other than english are displays like `?????`. How can I export the database to support all language contents. Please help me Or suggest me other way to convert mysql database to sqlite . Thanks in advance.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that the data in the database is correctly encoded, just add `--default-character-set=utf8` to the `mysqldump` options.